# Cannot push update to Code Push when using dynamic version name on different build types

Tags: android, ios, react-native, code-push, visual-studio-app-center

I'm using React Native to develop a mobile app for Android and iOS. I have 3 different build types/configuration (Android/iOS). On Android, I have debug, releaseStaging, and release (for production). And on iOS I have debug, release, production.

To differentiate version name between production and development, I use versionNameSuffix on release build Android. 
On iOS, I create some variables which is VERSION_NAME (e.g 1.0), VERSION_NAME_SUFFIX (I use -beta for debug and release build config), and VERSION_NAME_STRING which is the concatenation of VERSION_NAME and VERSION_NAME_SUFFIX (so on debug/release I get 1.0-beta, and production 1.0)

Now I want to push some updates to codepush. I use command

`appcenter codepush release-react -a org/appName -t "1.0-beta" -d Staging --mandatory`

And I got an error

`Error: Invalid binary version(s) for a release.`

Can anybody help me ? I need different version name for development and production, and I also need to use App Center Code Push

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version number needs to be semver compliant which 1.0-beta isn't. If you use 1.0.0-beta instead it should work fine.